# ORM framework for Redis while using Vertx

Tags: java, orm, redis, vert.x

I am looking for a "spring data Redis" solution.

The thing is that I am using Vertx and I dont want to Inject Spring inside.

Iam looking for annotation solution that will map my objects(aka entities) to Redis.

I could Inject vertx to Spring. and used the eventbus to integrate between the two.

I have two candidate to solution:

1. Each request I get via the vertx eventbus I am going to send it over kafka and have spring consumer in the other side(this way Spring will handle the "redis" work forme
2. I am going to use redis straight inside Vertx (using Jedis or any other redis client) and manage all redis layers (dao,dto's) myself

What do you experts think?

Thank you,
ray.

Comment: You right. I added additional description and what I thought so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key-value store. OR/M frameworks are meant to resolve the issue of storing objects in a non-hierarchical data store like a relational database.

Just because OR/M means "object-relational mapping" you can't expect an "OR/M for Redis".

Comment: In my scenario I want to retrieve user details by userId(and by that convert the json to pojo). Thats why I wanted some ORM example.